# Manually recompose all AndroidView in JetPack Compose

Tags: android, view, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

In my project I use JetPack Compose and the AndroidView to use an XML View.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MyComposable(
    message: String
) {

    AndroidView(
        factory = { context ->

            TextView(context).apply {
                text = message
            }

        })
}
```

My issue is that when my `message` state change, the XML view in the `AndroidView` isn't recomposed. There is an option in the `AndroidView` to obverse the state change ?

ps: I've simplified `MyComposable` for the example

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the `update` block.

From the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/viewinterop/package-summary#AndroidView(kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Function1)):

> The `update` block can be run multiple times (on the UI thread as well) due to recomposition, and it is the right place to set `View` properties depending on state. **When state changes, the block will be reexecuted to set the new properties**. Note the block will also be ran once right after the `factory` block completes

```
AndroidView(
    factory = { context ->

        TextView(context).apply {
            text = "Initial Value"
        }
    },
    update = {
        it.text =  message
    }
)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly ! Have a nice day !

Comment: Notably, update() will change the properties of the view constructed inside of the factory(). But it will not reexecute the entire factory block with the new property.  So if the view is complex and requires some tinkering, and you can't figure out why it's not updating, you might need to reiterate some of the factory() logic inside of update().