# Google maps won't recompose Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm building the Map using `AndroidView()` composable and putting markers on the map with locations that come from a flow inside a `viewModel`.

The list will update after the api call is successful.

The problem is that even when the flow emits a new value the `AndroidView()` won't recompose.

If I used for example a `Text` composable and put the values from the flow it will recompose.

That's the code I'm using to create the Google map:

```
@Composable
fun MapView() {
    val mapView = rememberMapWithLifecycle()
    val viewModel: HomeViewModel = hiltViewModel<HomeViewModelImpl>()
    val nearbyCars = viewModel.nearbyCars.collectAsState()
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .fillMaxHeight()
    ) {
        val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

            AndroidView(factory = {
                mapView
            }) {
                coroutineScope.launch {
                    val map = it.awaitMap()
                    map.uiSettings.isZoomControlsEnabled = true
                    nearbyCars.value.forEach { location ->
                        val marker = MarkerOptions().title(location.toString()).position(location)
                        map.addMarker(marker)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

I've been following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/geekculture/google-maps-in-jetpack-compose-android-ae7b1ad84e9), as there seems to be quite a few about Compose + Google maps.

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/67916673/1531621

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide an update callback.[The AndroidView recomposes whenever a State read within the callback changes.](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/interop-apis#views-in-compose)

```
@Composable
fun CustomView() {
    val selectedItem = remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

    // Adds view to Compose
    AndroidView(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), // Occupy the max size in the Compose UI tree
        factory = { context ->
            // Creates custom view
            CustomView(context).apply {
                // Sets up listeners for View -> Compose communication
                myView.setOnClickListener {
                    selectedItem.value = 1
                }
            }
        },
        update = { view ->
            // View's been inflated or state read in this block has been updated
            // Add logic here if necessary

            // As selectedItem is read here, AndroidView will recompose
            // whenever the state changes
            // Example of Compose -> View communication
            view.coordinator.selectedItem = selectedItem.value
        }
    )
}
```

For google maps and compose together I come across this [compose-sample](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/main/Crane/app/src/main/java/androidx/compose/samples/crane/details/DetailsActivity.kt). But for more complicated scenarios you can check [Mitch's solution](https://youtu.be/J8OqN-JqWlQ).